# array comparison template operator== does not apply

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written a nice comparison template for c-style arrays as seen below.
The only problem is: **the operator== is not applied (not found?) by the compiler** in the following simple code:

```
int Array1[3];
int Array2[3];
bool is_equal = ( Array1 == Array2 );
```

Here is my template

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
bool operator==( const T ( &A )[N], const T ( &B )[N] )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
    {
        if ( A[i] != B[i] )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If I rename the `operator==(...)` to `Equals(...)` everything works fine. 
**Why is this???**

I also am unsure about the placement of const in the function. Obviously, I want to use 'const &' as for any good comparison operator.

Comment: Because you cannot compare arrays in C++. C++ does not work this way. Use either `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: You cannot overload operators on fundamental types. An overloaded operator must take at least one parameter of class or enum type.

Comment: Oops. Strangely enough, there is no warning in VC++.

Comment: Did not realize that `T ( &A )[N]` was a fundamental type.

Comment: That's the thing, you **can** define such operator but it will never be used. It would be nice if someone could explain **why** it works this way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Great Job reading past the first line!

Comment: @r3musn0x - Because to do otherwise would make it really hard to determine the meaning of programs. To the extent that including a different header might change a program's meaning unintentionally. We don't want that.

Comment: @StoryTeller This problem ALWAYS can occur with operator overloading

Comment: @old123987 - Not to that great an extent. If you can't reason about the very basic of statements, writing programs becomes intractable.

Comment: As for not getting a peep from MSVC. That's a QoI issue. [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e423932788d69da7) is quite clear on this, for example.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thx. Should have tried this myself...